# how to clear PDB string in a release VC++ build

Tags: c++, path, pdb-files

I have an EXE built from Visual Studio and I'd like to clear or just remove the path portion of the PDB filename.  I'm looking for a tool to make this adjustment in the PE's debug directory, without using a hex editor.  Many have suggested BinPlace, but I can't get this to work.  I have yet to see a command line for binplace that actually works for this purpose. Other Microsoft tools have been suggested and these tools have literally no documentation besides the command line help.  The command line help also indicates that's not what these tools are for (e.g. pdbstr).  Again, people making these suggestions post no command line usage information and since these tools aren't documented, I'm back at square one.  Relinking is not an option for me in this case but I am aware of the linker switches that alter this information.  Are there any tools that will work with clearing PDB path information from an EXE or do you have a binplace command line that works?

Answer (score 0):

peupdate can be downloaded here:

http://bytepointer.com/tools/index.htm#peupdate

This tool can be used to list, remove or change the PDB string in an executable module.  The following example clears the entire PDB string (path and filename):

```
peupdate -c <module_path>
```

To strip the PDB path and leave the PDB filename allowing symbol lookup to still work when debugging module if symbol paths properly set up (e.g. "c:\joeblow\test.pdb" changes to "test.pdb"):

```
peupdate -s <module_path>
```

To change the PDB path: (any arbitrary string)

```
peupdate -u <new_path> <module_path>
```